# Label for file upload button is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a label for a file-upload button, which is styled. If I click the button, it isn't opening the file dialogue.

My html code looks like this:

```
<div class="file-input">
      <input type="file" class="file">
      <label for="file">Choose file...</label>
</div>
```

My css code looks like this:

```
.file
{
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  position: absolute;
}
.file-input label
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #ff6ec4, #7873f5);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}
```

I tried to click the button, but it didn't open the file dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you set style for this class '.file'

```
.file {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```